# Getting the Employee id of the Log User in Odoo - 8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

Good Day I have a problem in filtering of Odoo 8 Field
I just want to Select only the Employee id of the Log User i just add this in my XML

```
<field name="employee_id" style = "width:500px" domain = "[('id', '=', user.id.employee_id.id)]" options="{'no_create': True}"/>
```

But I have an Error it says

Uncaught Error: NameError: name 'user' is not defined.

Is there a right way to get the Employee Id of a Log User here in Odoo 8 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To obtain the employee of the logged user I do this way:

```
resource = self.env['resource.resource'].search([('user_id','=',self.env.user.id)])
employee = self.env['hr.employee'].search([('resource_id','=',resource.id)])
```

Of course it is not easy to put it inside a domain, thus maybe you can use a stored computed field to save the user_id of the employee inside your table, then you can write the domain this way:

```
[('user_id', '=', uid)]
```

Answer (score 2):

you may try with below domain:

Replace your code

```
[('id', '=', user.id.employee_id.id)]
```

with

```
[('employee_id.user_id','=',user.id)]
```

This will filter the user of employee. Based on Logged User, it filter for the Employee's User.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in much simpler way.
Try this
.py file

```
employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string=u"Employé", readonly=True, store=True, default=_employee_get)

def _employee_get(self):
    record = self.env['hr.employee'].search([('user_id', '=', self.env.user.login)]) 
    return record[0]
```